# Dynamic url routing in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am new in Laravel using version 5.8

I do not want to set route manually for every controller.

What i want is that if i give any url for example -

```
www.example.com/product/product/add/1/2/3

www.example.com/customer/customer/edit/1/2

www.example.com/category/category/view/1
```

for the above example url i want that url should be treated like

```
www.example.com/directoryname/controllername/methodname/can have any number of parameter
```

I have lots of controller in my project so i want this pattern should be automatically identified by route and i do not need to specify manually  again and again Directory Name, Controller , method and number of arguments(parameter) in route.

Comment: I think you missed resource controller and his routing declaration: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/controllers#resource-controllers

Comment: hey first read routing

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Route::get('/product/edit/{id}',[
    'uses' => 'productController@edit',
    'as'=>'product.edit'
]);
Route::get('/products',[
    'uses' => 'productController@index',
    'as'=>'products'
]);
```

in the controller:

```
 public function edit($id)
{
    $product=Product::find($id);

    return view('edit')->with('product',$product);
}
public function index()
{
    $products=Product::all();
    return view('index')->with('products',$products);
}
```

in the index view

```
@foreach($products as $product)
    <a href="{{ route('product.edit',['id'=>$product->id]) }}">Edit</a>
@endforeach
```

in the edit view

```
<p>$product->name</p>
<p>$product->price</p>
```